# Firebase - getToken() throws Unsupported MIME type

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a react-create-app application, in which I used firebase for pushnotification. Recently I upgraded **firebase** from 8.* to 9.*. While getting push token, it throws the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://9fd5-49-204-137-92.ngrok.io/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://9fd5-49-204-137-92.ngrok.io/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
```

In firebase.js, I have the following code set, which throws the above mentioned error

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getToken, getMessaging, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

const message_key = "key"

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apikey",
  authDomain: "authdomain",
  projectId: "project-app",
  storageBucket: "******.com",
  messagingSenderId: "id",
  appId: "appid",
  measurementId: "mid"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 let messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
        .then(function(registration) {
          console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration);
    
          getToken({messaging, vapidKey: message_key})
          .then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
              console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
            } else {
              console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:", err);
        });
        }}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Moving firebase-messaging-sw.js file to public directory solved the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //firebase .js
    
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";
    // import firebase from "firebase";
    
    // Replace these values with your project's ones
    // (you can find such code in the Console)
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "your key",
      authDomain: "your authDomain",
      projectId: "your projectId",
      storageBucket: "your storageBucket",
      messagingSenderId: "your messagingSenderId",
      appId: "your appId",
      measurementId: "your measurementId",
    };
    
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // const messaging = getMessaging();
    
    export const getTokenFirebase = (setTokenFound) => {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
            .then(function (registration) {
              console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration);
    
              if (permission === "granted") {
                const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
    
                getToken(messaging, {
                  vapidKey:
                    "your web push key",
                })
                  .then((currentToken) => {
                    if (currentToken) {
                      console.log("currentToken", currentToken);
                    } else {
                      console.log(
                        "No registration token available. Request permission to generate one."
                      );
                    }
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("currentToken= ", err);
                    // catch error while creating client token
                  });
              } else {
                console.log("Notification not granted.");
              }
            });
        }
      });
    };







    //firebase-messaging-sw.js
 //create file inside public folder add below code

//public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gsta`enter code here`tic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js");
firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).